# Accessing an object from a different class - Design

Tags: c++, class, image-processing, class-design, c++builder

I have three classes, `TImageProcessingEngine`, `TImage` and `TProcessing`

`TImageProcessingEngine` is the one which i am using to expose all my methods to the world.

`TImage` is the one i plan to use generic image read and image write  functions.

`TProcessing` contains methods that will perform imaging operations.

```
class TImageProcessingEngine
{
    public:
        TImage* mpImageProcessingEngine;

};

class TImage
{
    public:
        int ReadImage();
        int WriteImage();

    private:
            //a two dimensional array holding the pixel values
        tImageMatrix*  mpImageMatrix;
};

class TProcessing
{
    public:
        int ConvertToBinary();
        int ConvertToGrayScale();
};
```

My question is **how do i access the object `mpImageMatrix` in class `TProcessing`?** So that my calling application can use the following

```
TImageProcessingEngine* vEngine = new TImageProcessingEngine;

//Converts an input gray scsale image to binary image
vEngine->ReadImage().ConvertToBinary();

//Write the converted image to disk
vEngine->WriteImage();

delete vEngine;
vEngine = NULL;

//During this whole processing internally, 
//the image is read in to `mpImageMatrix` 
//and will also be holding the binarised image data, 
//till writing the image to disk.
```

Or **Do you recommend any other approach to my class design?**

Comment: you should try and use less `new` and less pointers, taking advantage of the automatic cleanup provided for values. Also it's bad practice to set a pointer to `null` after delete'ing it, it hides bugs.

Comment: Setting a pointer to NULL after a delete 'hides bugs'?  Quite the opposite, setting it NULL ensures that any access of the pointer after the delete throws an exception (granted: on most C++ compilers.  On all C++ compilers for x86)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would certainly recommend a different implementation, but let's check the design first.

I don't really understand the added value of `TImageProcessingEngine`, it doesn't bring any functionality.

My advice would be quite simple in fact:

- `Image` class, to hold the values
- `Processing` class (interface), to apply operations
- `Encoder` and `Decoder` classes (interfaces), to read and write to different formats

It does make sense for the `Processing` class to have access to the images internal only if you can get efficiency from it (which is likely), in this case you can simply makes `Processing` friend and having it unpack the values for its derived

```
class Image
{
public:
  Image();

  void Accept(Processing& p);
  void Encode(Encoder& e) const; // Image is not modified by encoding

  void Decode(Decoder& d); // This actually resets the image content

private:
  friend class Processing;

  size_t mHeight;
  size_t mWidth;
  std::vector<Pixel> mPixels; // 2D array of Pixels
};

class Processing
{
public:
  void apply(Image& image)
  {
    this->applyImpl(image.mHeight, image.mWidth, image.mPixels);
  }

private:
  virtual void applyImpl(size_t h, size_t w, std::vector<Pixel>& pixels) = 0;
};
```

`Encoder` and `Decoder` follow the same principle.

Note how I never needed an explicit pointer, and the guaranteed correctness that results from it.

Comment: Your reply is more than what i was expecting. Thank you. Can you please explain how you declare this object Pixel in the following statement? std::vector<Pixel> mPixels; // 2D array of Pixels
Thanks

Comment: @Raj: well, what is a `Pixel` for you ? You said you had a matrix of pixels so I assumed you would know how to represent them. Typical representations include RGB or YCMV etc...

Answer (score 1):

First off, based on your provided code there are no ReadImage() & WriteImage() functions in the TImageProcessingEngine class, so the later code where you use such functionality is flawed.

As for the solution, you can make a getter function for the tImageMatrix pointer like this:

```
tImageMatrix* GetImageMatrix() { return mpImageMatrix; }
```

Then just pass that pointer (or a pointer to the whole TImage instance) to the TProcessing function you want to call.

Comment: i have declared TImage* mpImageProcessingEngine; in class TImageProcessingEngine; So i can call ReadImage() & WriteImage() methods.

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to have a separate `TProcessing` process, when it specifically has functions just accessing `mpImageMatrix;`

In OOP, you have to *bind* **the data members and it's operations**..

So, IMO, remove your `TProcessing` class and have both the functions within `TImage`..

Your `TImage` will be like,

```
class TImage
{
public:
    int ReadImage();
    int WriteImage();
    int ConvertToBinary();
    int ConvertToGrayScale();

private:
        //a two dimensional array holding the pixel values
    tImageMatrix*  mpImageMatrix;
};
```

Comment: Some people prefer to have class that has only 1 purpose. Therefore having a seperate Image processing class, next to a Image class which just is an image.

Comment: @PoweRoy, Yeah, sounds valid for me... Thanx... :)

Comment: +1 @liaK, This is what i have implemented in the first place. But i wanted to move away from this. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an accessor `TImage` class:

```
byte * pixelAt(unsigned x, unsigned y);
```

Comment: Don't you think, this will be time costly, as you are trying to access an individual pixel?

Comment: If this function is inlined, you get no overhead.